# Aggregating objects by timestamp per day for a timespan of week

Tags: java, android, sql, loops, jodatime

I have problem with aggregating data based on their timestamp per day for a timespan of one week. There is a SQLite database, which has a table which I save the number of walking steps in (`timestamp` column is UTC and `created_At` is local time, but I don't use the created_at column anyway).

[image]

What I want to do is get the total data which happened in 7 days ago until the midnight of a day before. So I have this `jodatime` expression to find start and end for timestamps

```
long start = new DateTime().withMillisOfDay(0).minusDays(7).getMillis();
long end = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
//start milli:1405029600000 DateTime: 2014-07-11 00:00:00
//end milli:1405634400000   DateTime: 2014-07-18 00:00:00
```

Then I execute this sql command:

```
SELECT * FROM pa_data WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1405029600000 AND 1405634400000
```

And I am pretty sure that it returns the correct rows ( I have compared the android database result with SQLite Database Browser on my pc, both return same number of rows). For this, I tried to use this nested iteration:

the Object I am trying to create is:

```
public class PhysicalActivityPerDay {

    private List<PhysicalActivity> mList;

    public PhysicalActivityPerDay(List<PhysicalActivity> list) {
        mList = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivity>(list);
    }

    //methods....

}
```

Now the problem is, I want to have a data object that can hold the rows for each day.

```
List<PhysicalActivity> all = getPhysicalActivitiesBetween(start, end);
List<PhysicalActivityPerDay> perDays = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivityPerDay>();
List<PhysicalActivity> tempList;
PhysicalActivityPerDay tempPerDay;    

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    long begin = start;
    long stop = (begin + 86400000); //add 24 hours

    tempList = new ArrayList<PhysicalActivity>();

    for (int j = 0; j < all.size(); j++) {

        PhysicalActivity p = all.get(j);
        DateTime when = new DateTime(p.getTimestamp());

        if (when.isAfter(start) && when.isBefore(stop)) {
            tempList.add(p);
            all.remove(j); //remove the matching object from the list
        }
    }

    tempPerDay = new PhysicalActivityPerDay(tempList);
    perDays.add(tempPerDay);

    start += 86400000; //add 24 hours or 1 day for next iteration
}

return perDays;
```

But the result is totally unexpected. There are many rows which don't match the `if` statements above. I did a debug and here is what happens:

```
Log.w(TAG, "There are totally " + all.size() + " physical activities for day for 7 days");
//There are totally 6559 physical activities for day for 7 days
```

But, when I check the `all` list (total rows returned by DB) although I am removing matched objects from it, if I query its size after the nested iteration, it surprisingly still contains many objects in it, telling me that the iteration was not successful!

```
//Remaining: 3278 records after iterations from 6559
```

What I am doing wrong? please help me findout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if that's the only problem :

You are looping over the `all` List, and removing items.
When you call `all.remove(j)`, the item that used to be at position j+1 moves to poisition j. Which means your for loop would skip that item.

One way to solve this is to increment j only if you don't remove an item from the list.

```
for (int j = 0; j < all.size();) {

    PhysicalActivity p = all.get(j);
    DateTime when = new DateTime(p.getTimestamp());

    if (when.isAfter(start) && when.isBefore(stop)) {
        tempList.add(p);
        all.remove(j); //remove the matching object from the list
    } else {
        j++;
    }
}
```

Actually, I'm not entirely sure if the loop would work after this fix. It depends whether `all.size()` is evaluated in each iteration. If it isn't, it would expect the list to have the initial number of elements, even though you are removing items. In that case you can expect to get an exception the first time you try to access an index beyond the last index of the array.

If you get an exception, you can replace the loop with a while loop :

```
Iterator<PhysicalActivity> iter = all.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext ()) {
  PhysicalActivity p = iter.next();
  ...
  if (...) {
    iter.remove();
  }
}
```

Refer to the [definition of List.remove()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) :

> public E remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. **Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices)**.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that was the problem! may you also give your opinion about the performance of the code, can it be any better?

Answer (score 0):

How about letting SQL perform your aggregation for you

```
    SELECT strftime('%W-%Y',dt) as weekYear, count(1) as occurencePerWeek 
    FROM SOMETABLE c GROUP BY weekYear;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e63c3/1

Comment: its SQLite I am not sure if it has this feature

Comment: Yes it has. Click on SQLFiddle link, I used SQLlite engine.